# wordpress php add post category as class to post item

Tags: php, wordpress, class, categories

I am displaying the featured image for all my posts on one page (the image then links to the individual post). I want to give each post from the same category the same class (which will be the name of the category slug), so for example, if a post is in a category called "cat1" I would like the div that contains the post to have the class "cat1" and so on.

So far I have this:

```
<article class="<?php get_the_category($post->ID)?>">
```

but this just returns blank, can someone tell me what I'm missing here please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class#Add_Classes_By_Filters) is your friend:

```
// add category nicenames in body and post class
function so20621481_category_id_class($classes) {
    global $post;
    foreach((get_the_category($post->ID)) as $category)
        $classes[] = $category->category_nicename;
    return $classes;
}
add_filter('post_class', 'so20621481_category_id_class');
```

NB: for this to work, your article element should contain the `post_class` template tag:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
```